# ILNumerics mkl_custom dll not found

Tags: c#, dll, ilnumerics

We have two applications that use ILNumerics and have run into the same issue with both.  We use the mkl_custom.dll and during development the application runs fine.  The dll in use during development sits in the bin32 folder automatically generated when downloading the ILNumerics from nuget.  However when we install the applications we get "Unable to load DLL 'mkl_custom': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HResult: 0x8007007E".

Here is what we have tried:

- Building the application in Any CPU, x86.
- Switching the bin32 to include the bin64 dll's and viсе-versa.
- Running dependency walker and including all dll's that are needed.
- Changing path variable.

We are using ILNumerics 3.3.3.0.

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Copy to output directory" of all the .dll's under the bin32 and bin64 folder to "Copy Always?

Answer (score 0):

One of the dependencies for mkl_custom is msvcr*.dll. Packing this dll manually may work on some operating systems but not all. Make sure the target system has c++ runtime redistributable package installed. 
This installs the msvcr dll correctly. Hopefully this should fix the issue